# Setting up Illuminate query builder - Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to set up Illuminate query builder, so I can run queries like "DB::table('table')->where(...)" .. however I can't get it to work.

I downloaded Laravel throught composer (require laravel/laravel). Next I have created a index.php, where I am including composer autoload file. After that, I am trying to call a simple query:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('users')->get();
```

However it throws exception "Uncaught RuntimeException: A facade root has not been set.". I was not expecting it to work right away, because I didn't specified the database connection. But based on the message of this exception I am not much clever.

I found a solution here on SO to put this before using query builder:

```
$Capsule = new Capsule;
$Capsule->addConnection(config::get('database'));
$Capsule->setAsGlobal();
$Capsule->bootEloquent();
```

However the `config::get('database')` statement throws the same exception too. Which means I probably have to configure the config somehow too.

I have tried to include Laravel's bootstrap and boot it, but it does not change anything.

```
$app = require_once '\composer\vendor\laravel\laravel\bootstrap\app.php';
$app->boot();
```

Then I tried to set Config's facade app by this statement: `Config::setFacadeApplication($app)` After that, when I try to call Config::get('database'), it throws other exception `Uncaught ReflectionException: Class config does not exist`

Now I am out of ideas how to get it working. What am I missing here?

Comment: "Next I have created a index.php, where I am including composer autoload file." This is where you're going wrong. Laravel does a crapload of bootstrapping before any user code is actually called. Either do it the laravel way, or bootstrap everything manually I guess.

Comment: move your code to e.g. `./routes/web.php`

Comment: And do I even need Laravel? Can't I just somehow use the standalone Illuminate query builder?

Comment: by jumping through some hoops, yes, but you might also want to look at `lumen`, its laravel's lightweight little brother

Comment: You can, but you probably shouldn't require the entire framework if you only need one component. You can also look at more independent query building libraries like Pixie, Hydrahon or something in between like Doctrine.

Comment: Quezler - I am not using web, I am calling the script from the command line

Comment: thanks, I'll take a look at other alternatives ... but still, I would like to find some solution to this problem (as I might use some other Illuminate functionalities in future)

Comment: you could use `php artisan` in either laravel or lumen, or a standalone composer alltogether

Comment: @MalikLekvar the solution is to either wrap everything in Commands or to bootstrap the framework yourself. The first is fairly easy (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan ), the last is hard but gives you very fine control of what you exactly want to use.

Comment: thanks, i have probably chose the second way - bootstrap framework by myself. it looks nice and it's working!

Answer (score 1):

Solved by extending an Application class and defining config and db instances in bootstrap function, like this:

```
use Illuminate\Config\Repository;
use Illuminate\Database\Connectors\ConnectionFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\DatabaseManager;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

class LaravelApp extends Application
{

    function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        $this->instance('config', new Repository(['database' => $this->getDBCfg()]));
        $this->instance('db', new DatabaseManager($this, new ConnectionFactory($this)));
    }

    private function getDBCfg(){
        return [

            'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

            'connections' => [

                'mysql' => [
                    'driver' => 'mysql',
                    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
                    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
                    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'test'),
                    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
                    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
                    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
                    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
                    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
                    'prefix' => '',
                    'strict' => true,
                    'engine' => null,
                ],

            ],

        ];
    }
}
```

Client code looks like this:

```
$laravelApp = new LaravelApp(__DIR__);
$laravelApp->boot();
Config::setFacadeApplication($laravelApp);
var_dump(\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('test')->get());
```

Thanks for help in comments