# Trying to convert a query to eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following SQL:

```
SELECT arv.* 
FROM   article_reference_versions arv 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT `order`, 
                          Max(`revision`) AS max_revision 
                   FROM   article_reference_versions 
                   WHERE  `file` = '12338-230180-1-CE.doc' 
                   GROUP  BY `file`, 
                             `order`) AS b 
               ON arv.order = b.order 
                  AND arv.revision = b.max_revision 
WHERE  arv.file = '12338-230180-1-CE.doc'
```

I need to convert this to Eloquent, so that I can properly access the data in object form. I tried doing it as such,

```
$s = Models\EloArticleReferenceVersion::select(
    'SELECT arv.*
    FROM article_reference_versions arv
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT `order`, max(`revision`) as max_revision
            FROM article_reference_versions
            WHERE file = ? group by `file`, `order`) AS b
        ON 
            arv.order = b.order AND arv.revision = b.max_revision 
            WHERE arv.file = ?',
        [ 
            '12338-230180-1-CE.doc', 
            '12338-230180-1-CE.doc' 
        ])->get();
dd($s);
```

But I'm running into a plethora of issues, one after another. I figured it'd be easier to just convert this into an eloquent query, looking for some help with this.

Comment: What does EloArticleReferenceVersion's relationship to article_reference_versions  look like?

Comment: `EloArticleReferenceVersion` is a model for the `article_reference_versions` table. I'm trying to join it on itself

Answer (score 0):

DB Query to Query using Eloquent.

```
$query = EloArticleReferenceVersion::query()
    ->join(DB::raw('( SELECT `order`,Max(`revision`) AS max_revision FROM article_reference_versions WHERE  `file` = '12338-230180-1-CE.doc' GROUP  BY `file`, `order`) as sub_table'), function($join) {
    $join->on('sub_table.order', '=', 'article_reference_versions.order');
    $join->on('sub_table.max_revision ', '=', 'article_reference_versions.revision');
})
->where('article_reference_versions.file', '=', '12338-230180-1-CE.doc' )
->get();
```

**Not Tested**

Comment: This returns error `Object of class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder could not be converted to string`?

Comment: Now try. Sometimes formatted string query doesn't work well with DB::raw.

Comment: I was getting error `class DB not found`, so I fixed it with the `user Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38673289/laravel-5-class-db-not-found), but now I'm getting an error `A facade root has not been set.`

Comment: That's a strange error. Are you using a Laravel or Lumen?

Comment: Im using laravel :( It's just saying `Class 'DB' not found`

Comment: Can you try this solution:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213364/setting-up-illuminate-query-builder-uncaught-runtimeexception-a-facade-root-h